# what is the css slightly out for the menu

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Why is the css slightly out for the main menu.

In ie 7 the top menu is diagonal. if you go to the site you will see what i mean.

It is fine in firefox, if possible could you also check other browsers and notify me of problems.

thanks

Comment: If you'd like to know how your site looks in other browsers, I suggest http://browsershots.org/. There you can get screenshots from a broad variety of browsers on both Linux, Windows, and BSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `float` to your `li` instead of `<a>`

like this:

```
.wrappermenu ul li{
 float:left;
}
.wrappermenu ul li a{
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: thanks. but this has now pushed the menu up a little. how do i fix that?

Comment: give display:block to your <a> (.wrappermenu ul li a)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `float: left;` for `<li>` elements, not for `<a>` elements.

And then use `display: block;` for `<a>` elements.

Comment: thanks. but this has now pushed the menu up a little. how do i fix that?

Comment: You need `display: block;` for `<a>` links.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution

Apply inline css in li tag of your menu items. COde is as below :

```
*float: left;
```

Comment: this css is only apply for IE 7 not for other browser.

Comment: Why inline? Just to for the sake to repeat it? :)

Comment: Hmmm, to apply this in class is cool. :) rather than to repeat it.. :D

Comment: thanks. but this has now pushed the menu up a little. how do i fix that?

Comment: in IE 7 only??? or other browsers also??

Comment: thanks for replying. all browsers. i want it to look like it does in firefox for all browsers. thanks again

Comment: first you change css in link so that i can get idea what's the error behind it. then only i can give you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.wrappermenu ul li 
{
    float:left; 
}
```